# Accidentally Deleted my Database for a wordpress site

Tags: database, wordpress

I designed a site last year locally and copied it over to the clients hosting onces the site was complete.

A year later I needed to delete some of my old databases and it turns out one of the db was for that site.

I went back to my hosting provider who imformed me that they can not retrieve the file even though I can still see it although when I open it up in phpMyAdmin there are no wordpress tables in it.

The clients hosting company sent me the ftp details to re-download the website and I have all the latest elements however I do not have an XML file to upload all the latest pages and posts.

I have all the images, all the plugins and themes but nothing else.

Is there any way without me having to recreate the whole thing and creating a new database to establish the link back with the website.

Comment: Well, just to confirm, did you delete the database on your localhost or did you delete it on clients hosting? If you deleted it only from your localhost, then you still have the database on the live hosting server. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

well thats terrible, I would ask the host for a backup, my company swiftgrid.net backs up websites every day. its pretty common for the host to have a backup. If there is no backup the only other thing you could do is go to the http://archive.org/ and copy and paste the pages if there is a record.

Mathew